# Synonym Search in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, search, synonym

I am trying to implement "Synonym search in elastic using java as technology".
I will get a file from operations team for the synonyms keyword and I want to use that file and implement synonym search in java.
Please let me know the leads.

Comment: could you explain it with couple of examples and scenarios?

Comment: yes sure.--> suppose i have one text file synonyms.txt in which there are different synonyms defined ( kill-> murder). so if user search kill than murder should also be in response. this is synonym search in elastic which i have to implement in java.